# Rewrite rules in ISS's web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm just trying to get some code running on ISS that has been running on Apache for a long time.

A particular mod_rewrite rule is proving difficult to get working.

In Apache I've used:

```
RewriteRule ^media/(js|css|img|font)/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ /media/$1/$2.$4
```

[L]

To turn a URL like `/media/css/style.1367406756.css` into `/media/css/style.css`, letting me put timestamps in the files to avoid caching issues.

In my web.config file I've added:

```
<rule name="Cache bust assets" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$"/>
    <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^media/(js|css|img|font)/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/media/{R:1}/{R:2}.{R:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Which, looks like it should work. (It's alongside another rule, which works fine, so it's not that the server isn't parsing it or anything).

I don't get any errors, other than visiting `/media/css/style.1367406756.css` gives me a 404 error.

How Can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `{R:N}` back references in your `action` when you should use `{C:N}` since the information comes from the `conditions`. See [Using Back-references in Rewrite Rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules) for more information.

You can see this error if you open the `iismanager` console:

[image: alerts]

To get your rule to work you have 2 solutions.

First you can change your action to (using `{C:N}`):

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/media/{C:1}/{C:2}.{C:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Or (and I do think it is a better solution), you can use the `Import mod_rewrite Rules` tool.

In the `iismanager` console, click on `Import Rules...` (on the right tab) and paste your `apache` rule:

[image: import]

This will create for you the following rule:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^media/(js|css|img|font)/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/media/{R:1}/{R:2}.{R:4}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Ah, I've never used a Windows server before, and didn't know about the GUI stuff – how would I typically access that remotely? Via RDP?

Comment: Yes, via RDP, you then run `inetmgr` and you've got the console.